# Atiyah Macdonald exercise 1.5

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove that:

> The contraction of a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A[[x]]]$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, and $\mathfrak{m}$ is generated by $\mathfrak{m}^c$ and $x$.

I have made the following progress:

Suppose $x\not\in \mathfrak{m}$. Then $1-xg \in \mathfrak{m}$ for some $g\in A[[x]]$, and this is a contradiction because $1-xg$ is a unit. Therefore, $x\in \mathfrak{m}$. Consider any nonzero element $a\in A$. We want to show that there is $b \in A$ such that $ab \equiv 1 \ (\mathfrak{m}^c)$. Since $A[[x]]/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field, we know there is $f = \sum a_nx^n\in A[[x]]$ such that $af \equiv 1 \ (\mathfrak{m})$, and since $x\in \mathfrak{m}$, $aa_0 \equiv 1 \ (\mathfrak{m})$. How do I conclude from this that $aa_0 \equiv 1 \ (\mathfrak{m}^c)$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember what the symbols mean!  By definition, $aa_0 \equiv 1 \ (\mathfrak{m})$ means $aa_0-1\in\mathfrak{m}$.  But since $aa_0-1\in A$, this means $aa_0-1\in\mathfrak{m}^c$ as well.

Comment: So my confusion is this: suppose $\phi: A \mapsto A[[x]]$ is the ring homomorphism; then how do we show $\phi(aa_0 -1) \in \mathfrak{m}$?

Comment: You already showed that $aa_0-1\in\mathfrak{m}$, and $\phi$ is just the inclusion map.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question but why is it necessary that $\phi$ is the inclusion map?

Comment: That's tacit in the question: it is asking you about the contraction of $\mathfrak{m}$ with respect to the inclusion map $A\to A[[x]]$, not some random other homomorphism $A\to A[[x]]$.

Comment: I realize that now. Thanks!