Contraction of maximal ideals of power series ring is also maximal
Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of the power series ring $R[[x]]$.
I can see that $M \cap R$ is a prime ideal of R. But how do I show that this is maximal in $R$ ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Try to consider the local ring $R[[x]]_{M}$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297215/atiyah-macdonald-exercise-1-5
